# How do I end the forced camera angle when the monster is successfully hunted?

Tags: monster-hunter-rise

Whenever a monster is either killed or captured (or repelled), there's a forced camera angle spin around the defeated monster. In previous games, this was skippable through pressing either the relevant START or SELECT button, based on the platform. However, hitting + button on the Switch controller doesn't seem to end this forced camera angle spin in Rise. If possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that pressing B (the bottom button of the A-B-X-Y diamond or the A button on PC with an Xbox Controller) ends this forced camera view early, bringing the camera back to you and allowing you to see what you are doing.

As extra information, this forced camera view of the target does not actually cause you to lose control of your hunter. You can still move, attack, or use items during this period, you just aren't looking at yourself. I have been able to see that I sheath my weapon and walk toward the monster if I'm close enough to be in the frame.